# Dois listen no mesmo server

Tags: node.js

Estou criando um game server e neste game server vão ter vários canais pertencentes ao mesmo servidor, ai estava pensando se é possível criar dois listen no mesmo server, exemplo:

```
var net = require('net');

var server = net.createServer((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', onDataFunction());
});

server.listen(8945, '192.168.0.8', () => {
    console.log('Canal 1 iniciado');
});

server.listen(8945, '192.168.0.15', () => {
    console.log('Canal 2 iniciado');
});
```

Isso funcionaria normalmente ?

Comment: Sim, mas não na mesma porta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode criar outra instância do http e coloque-a para escutar a porta do seu interesse.
Exemplo:

```
    var http = require('http');

    http.createServer(onRequest_a).listen(9011);
    http.createServer(onRequest_b).listen(9012);

    function onRequest_a (req, res) {
      res.write('Response from 9011\n');
      res.end();
    }

    function onRequest_b (req, res) {
      res.write('Response from 9012\n');
      res.end();
    }
```

Faça o teste com navegador ou curl:

```
    $ curl http://localhost:9011
    Response from 9011

    $ curl http://localhost:9012
    Response from 9012
```